# Error while loading logging, invalid LOC Header

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pom.xml

I have following pom.xml :-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'am getting following error on running code :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

I understand that Logging is available in Spark 1.5.2 or earlier version but I want to work on 2.1 version and all my jar are upgraded then why I'm getting this logging error and how to get rid of it without downgrading any jar

My code is :-

```
 val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Test Data")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.40:9092")
  .option("zookeeper.connect", "192.168.0.40:2181")
  .option("subscribe", "topic")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("max.poll.records", 100)
  .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
  .load()
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[event].schema

 val ds = df.select(from_json($"value" cast "string", schema)).as[event]

val query = ds.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .queryName("table")
  .format("console")
  .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: why did you exclude the log4j and slf4j from the spark and kafka dependencies?

Comment: If I include I get this error - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)